# How to hide inherited control mark in design mode

Tags: c#, winforms, designmode, visual-inheritance

[image]

In screenshot you can see two forms:

1. Control in Design Mode which have inherited controls. This control's marked by a special symbol.
2. Print preview form which also contains this symbol.

Question:

How to remove (or make invisible) this symbol on form or at least on Print preview?

Comment: as far as I know, that icon is shown only at design time, why the hell does your `Print Preview` (which should be shown at runtime) have such icons shown/printed?

Comment: The same question.. Still can't figure out

Answer (score -1):

A sick way would be to search for the "icon" in all your resource files and replace it with an image that is empty but I guess that is not what you want ;-)

Comment: that icon is coming from the vs designer, it's not in her project resource files so he can't remove them.

Comment: Actually I did not mean the project resource files, I ment the resource files of the system where the application is running. It is clearly an image and this image must be located in either the corresponding resource files of the IDE or it is in a system wide resource file. It is like choosing an icon for a shortcut on the desktop. These icons are taken from system resource files too.